# How to pass values to a Flask app in EC2 instance using Public DNS or IP address?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I have a flask application in the Ubuntu EC2 instance. Locally I can pass the parameters For eg:
'''http://0.0.0.0:8888/createcm?summary=VVV&change=Feauure '''
where summary and change are parameters. How can I pass the same values from outside the EC2 (i.e) using Public DNS or IP address. Any other way to pass the parameters outside the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how works flask but i wont try help u.

At first as flask look like u shoud be able to do same like 'http://0.0.0.0:8888/createcm?summary=VVV&change=Feauure ' to outside, but you need open ports on your outside machine, like u should do on ec2 instance(i would do it with UFW firewall)

Other way its use rabbitmq or AWS S3 to communicate it